# ActiveWeb web application does not run under Jetty

Tags: java, web-applications, jetty, activeweb

I have created [sample web application](http://javalite.io/five_minute_guide_to_activeweb), packaged it into `WAR`, then put it into `webapps` folder into jetty. And it does not work.

[image]

Proof, windows from top to bottom:

1) The content of `GreetingController.java`

2) The compiled file is present inside `WAR` file in appropriate place

3) The web application is working, it's name is recognized (folder content displayed)

4) Controller is not working and it's name is not recognized

What else to check?

**UPDATE**

My WAR file: https://www.sendspace.com/file/mb94jt

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing something in your app. The page you are referring is just a guide to help understand how the framework works. For complete simple examples, please refer to:

- https://github.com/javalite/activeweb-bootstrap - this is a simple app with Bootstrap and no database support
- https://github.com/javalite/activeweb-lessc - simple app without database, but with Less instead of CSS
- https://github.com/javalite/activeweb-simple - simple ActiveWeb + ActiveJDBC webapp (CRUD)

Here is the Getting Started page: http://javalite.io/getting_started_activeweb

hope it helps

Comment: What else can be missed? My app consists of only one class with one empty method `index()`.

Comment: I do not know what you are missing since I do not have access to your code. But since it is not working for you, something is missing. Did you have a chance to look at examples?